# Background services with Meteor and Cordova

Tags: cordova, mobile, meteor, background

I'm currently trying to build a mobile app mainly for Android using Meteor and having some issues making the app to create a background service so that it works on certain things even when the app is completely closed.

Is this possible with a non-native app? Since I'm building it with Meteor but it uses Cordova as well, am I able to use the [bgs-core](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core) plugin?

//Edit: To better clarify, I'm trying to get background (even when app is closed) geolocation from an app.

Comment: When app is background then JS code will be stop. You only use native code to track geolocation when app closed.